# Getting bytes/sec on a Guzzle transfer

Tags: guzzle

Is it possible to calculate the bytes/sec on GET requests created by Guzzle 4 or 5?

If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes it is possible to calculate the data rate.

Assuming the usage of Guzzle 5, and from the [Guzzle Documentation on Events](https://web.archive.org/web/20150510110320/http://docs.guzzlephp.org:80/en/latest/events.html?) on the ProgressEvent:

> You can access the emitted progress values using the corresponding
> public properties of the event object:
>
> ```
> $downloadSize: The number of bytes that will be downloaded (if known)
> $downloaded: The number of bytes that have been downloaded
> $uploadSize: The number of bytes that will be uploaded (if known)
> $uploaded: The number of bytes that have been uploaded
> ```

In theory using an EventSubscriber (neat, tidy and recommended) or by passing closures to the event emitter (not so neat) is:

1. Start a timer on the BeforeEvent
2. Use the timer value and the ProgressEvent::downloaded to calculate a data rate.
3. Stop the timer within the CompleteEvent